# Search with parameters in Kibana

Tags: kibana, kibana-5

I'd like to search in Kibana for results with parameters.

For example :

Instead of writing in my search field:

```
title:foo AND name:foo AND address:foo
```

I would write :

```
title:param1 AND name:param1 AND address:param1
```

and pass the parameter `param1 = foo`

Is it possible ?